# Android/PlusClient:loadPeople returns incomplete PersonBuffer objects in onPeopleLoaded

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I'm doing some work with the Android/google_play_service library and the PlusClient. Specifically, I'm just filling up a ListView with the name of my contacts, along with some basic information available on their G+ profile page.

In order to load the list, I proceed as below:

```
// Create my PlusClient
activityContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
client = new PlusClient.Builder(activityContext, this, this)
           .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE, Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)
           .build();

// Load the people
//   this = the current activity
client.loadPeople(this, Person.Collection.VISIBLE);

// The below listener gets invoked when the list is loaded
... onPeopleLoaded(ConnectionResult cr, PersonBuffer pb, String nextPageToken) {
    Person contact = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < pb.getCount(); i++) {
        contact = pb.get(i);

        Log.d(TAG, contact.getDisplayName());
        Log.d(TAG, contact.getAboutMe() == null ? "Null" : contact.getAboutMe());
        Log.d(TAG, contact.getBirthday() == null ? "Null" : contact.getBirthday());
        Log.d(TAG, contact.getEmails() == null ? "Null" : contact.getEmails().toString());
        Log.d(TAG, contact.getCurrentLocation() == null ? "Null" : contact.getCurrentLocation());
        Log.d(TAG, contact.getId() == null ? "Null" : contact.getId());
        Log.d(TAG, contact.getLanguage() == null ? "Null" : contact.getLanguage());
        Log.d(TAG, contact.getUrl() == null ? "Null" : contact.getUrl());
        Log.d(TAG, contact.getName() == null ? "Null" : contact.getName().toString());
        Log.d(TAG, contact.isPlusUser() ? "true" : "false");
        Log.d(TAG, contact.isVerified() ? "true" : "false");
    }
}
```

In the code snippet above, the only methods that are not returning null are:
- getDisplayName
- getId
- getUrl

... and that for all my contacts (a few hundreds). It would appear like the Person objects contained into the PersonBuffer received in my method onPeopleLoaded are incomplete. For many of my contacts, the information I see on their G+ profile is visible (they are sharing it with me)...

On a side note, I tried the API explorer (https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) and I still get partial data, but at least, the 2 following methods seem to be working while they aren't with my android app:
- isPlusUser
- isVerified

Any information explaining that behavior would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all of that data is expected to be available for every user. Only data that users have set to be public on their profile OR access to data that is explicitly granted in the authorization dialog. With the `PLUS_LOGIN` scope that you specify, you can expect at a minimum: basic profile data (name, ID, photo, profile URL), ageRange, language, and list of friends that were made visible to the app.  Anything beyond that has to be made explicitly public by the user on their Google+ profile.

There are also "has" methods if you need to check for the existence of data prior to using the getter. See [com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.html) for all of the profile methods.